How to group point clouds by distance？
I scattered some points, how to group them according to distance and output them to the curve nodes, so that they become curves one by one


How do you define "groups" ? By  a minimal distance (two points further appart by this distance are in different groups) ?

You can convert the points to vertices, extrude them by 0 to make duplicated points connected with originals, merge those duplicates to connect points in groups by distance, store mesh island which is the group ID, delete duplicates and convert to curve using the group ID (old mesh island index):

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Curve will be same length，but what I want is group by group ,but no the same length

@leeedgar but you can clearly see the curves in my example aren't of the same length.

Thank you very much for cleverly utilizing the Boolean values of the extruded mesh
